# Problems using edit text with numbers in java

Tags: java, android

I am studying java on my own and I am creating an app that calculates areas, but when I enter a 1-digit number the app says I didn't put anything. But it works with decimals and 2-digit numbers. Can anyone help me to figure out why this is happening? That is the code:

```
public void calcRetangulo (View view){
    EditText compRet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.compRetangulo);
    EditText ladoRet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ladoRetangulo);

    if (compRet.getText().toString().matches("") || compRet.getText().toString().matches(".") && ladoRet.getText().toString().matches("") || ladoRet.getText().toString().matches(".")){

        LayoutInflater er = getLayoutInflater();

        View erro = er.inflate(R.layout.erro, null);

        erro.findViewById(R.id.ok).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                alertaErro.dismiss();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog.Builder builderErro = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builderErro.setView(erro);
        alertaErro = builderErro.create();
        alertaErro.show();

        compRet.setText("");
        ladoRet.setText("");

    } else{

        float comp = Float.parseFloat(compRet.getText().toString());
        float lado = Float.parseFloat(ladoRet.getText().toString());

        float area = comp * lado;

        LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();

        View result = li.inflate(R.layout.layout, null);
        final TextView resultado = (TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.resultado);

        resultado.setText(String.format("A = c x l\nA = "+ comp +" x " + lado +"\nA = "+ area));

        result.findViewById(R.id.fechar).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                alertaResult.dismiss();
                resultado.setText("");

            }
        });

        AlertDialog.Builder builderResult = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builderResult.setView(result);
        alertaResult = builderResult.create();
        alertaResult.show();

        compRet.setText("");
        ladoRet.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Vini, how "the app says"? Do you find errors on the logcat? If so, please paste a snippet here for us. Thanks from .br

Comment: I think your problem has to do with `Float.parseFloat`. Investigate how the round is done when using it with one digit number. Do it need to be a float? Can't you use some other type just for testing purposes? What you may do is a "format treatment" to the one digit data before this parsing, like adding something like `.0`... don't know. It is the case of trying options.

Answer (score 1):

`String.matches` in java is a regex.  So `matches(".")` will match any 1 digit string (. is a wildcard in regex).  If you want to match the literal string `"."`,  use `matches("\.")`

Comment: I tried it that way but it still didn't work, it shows that error: "Illegal escape character in string literal"

Answer (score 0):

Use the length of the EditText Text.
matches() is for regex expression.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `editText.getText().toString().contains("What ever you want")`